# Import STM32CubeMX code generated into Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, arm, stm32

I am trying to configure a STM32CubeMX project in order to import into Eclipse with the ARM GCC compiler.

Until now:

1. I downloaded Eclipse.
2. I [downloaded STM32CubeMX](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1533/PF259242?sc=stm32cube).
3. I downloaded the [GCC ARM toolchain](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+download).
4. I downloaded [Cross Build Tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuarmeclipse/files/Miscellaneous/).
5. I installed the [ARM plugin for Eclipse](http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/).

But now I don't know how to continue. STM32CubeMX generates code for Keil, Iar and TrueStudio projects (I can remember that in order to import code in Eclipse I need to generate code for a TrueStudio project). How do I have to import the code generated in Eclipse?

Comment: If you don't find a better solution you can still do it manually (add folders containing code in Eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

With the latest STM32Cube, it can generate toolchain code in SW4STM32.

It has an Eclipse plugin, which can meet your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

There is [a Eclipse-plugin available from ST](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1533/PF259242?s_searchtype=partnumber) that generates source for GCC (or go to st.com and search for CubeMx).

Download the zip file and install in Eclipse as a plugin. (Download the user manual for StCube - it describes how to do it.)

Comment: I had installed the plugin for eclipse but it is the same that standalone versión, is the same, the same UI and the same functions. It only allow you to generate code for iar, keil and truestudio. Any way I have been reading user manual (http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/user_manual/DM00104712.pdf) for STM32CubeMX and it tell you how to install the plugin but don't show how to generate code for eclipse.